# Getting backwards output when iterating through a map and printing content

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, maps

When I read through the code posted below it appears that the output printed would be:

```
Syndy
    James
    Phuong 
Germaine
    Agatha
    Anges
    Jack
```

However, when I run it I get Germaine and his vector of friends printed first, then Syndy and her vector of friends second:

```
Germaine
    Agatha
    Anges
    Jack
 Syndy
    James
    Phuong
```

Can anyone help me understand why Germaine, the second key, is accessed and printed first in the `printFacebook` function instead of Syndy?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void printFacebook(map<string, vector<string>>& m) {

    for (pair<string, vector<string>> p : m) {
        cout << p.first << endl;
        for (string f : p.second) {
            cout << "\t" << f << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    map<string, vector<string>> facebook;

    facebook["Syndy"].push_back("James");

    facebook.find("Syndy")->second.push_back("Phuong");
    //map<string, vector<string>>::iterator f = facebook.find("Syndy");
    //auto f = facebook.find("Syndy");

    facebook["Germaine"];
    facebook.find("Germaine")->second.push_back("Agatha");
    facebook.find("Germaine")->second.push_back("Anges");
    facebook.find("Germaine")->second.push_back("Jack");

    printFacebook(facebook);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::map` stores its items ordered by the value of the keys. In your case, the keys are `"Syndy"` and `"Germaine"`. The default ordering of those is such that `"Germaine"` is first and `"Syndy"` is second.

Hence, when you iterate over the items of the map, the item corresponding to the key `"Germaine"` is seen before the item corresponding to the key `"Syndy"`.

That explains the output.

Comment: So the std::map sorts itself? How does it  determine the order of the keys?

Comment: @StacksAndParsing, Yes. `std::map` has an optional parameter for comparing keys. The default is `std::less<Key>`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map for more details.